# WPF: How can I create sample data in design mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, designmode, sample-data

I would like to create sample data which are created only in design mode (When the WPF Window is shown in the Visual Studio WPF Designer or in Expression Blend). I tried this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        DataContext = new Person() { Name = "Harry" };
    }
}
```

It seems that the designer doesn't call the constructor of the Window class. I need to create the sample data in C# code because they are more complicated to instantiate. Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007091401.html

Comment: Using link from @sixlettervariables I managed it to work by using code. The key was to create a resource in XAML - instance of my custom DataProvider, with parameterless constructor filling my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I’m using the design-time support of Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend 4. This new feature meets most of my requirements.

How this works is shown in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads&referringTitle=Home). Please download the .Net4 version of WAF.

Answer (score 3):

If you do the setting of the DataContext in XAML, either directly or with a Binding, you avoid the issue of constructor skipping. The newer versions of the tools also support setting a d:DataContext that will only be invoked at design time to set the DataContext. If your instantiation can't be done directly in XAML (i.e. constructor parameters) you can just declare a get property in MainWindow.xaml.cs to instantiate and return your design data instance. Keeping the entire object creation in the getter will keep it from being created at run-time because it will never be called.

```
public MyData { get { return new Person() { Name = "Harry" }; } }
```

Then in XAML you can bind d:DataContext for the window to the new property.

```
d:DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MyData}"
```

There are many other options for doing this but this is the closest to the UI so usually the easiest to add into existing code. Josh Smith recently did a good overview of different options: [Design-time data is still data](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/design-time-data-is-still-data/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer – your solution looks really great. Unfortunately, I tried it with VS2010 but it didn’t work. Does this Binding really work for d:DataContext?